# How to count Am and PM in the date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have An excel file where the `date` is in this format `6/30/17 9:23 AM` I have many values in the date column

How can I count the total AM occurrence and total PM occurrence in the date column

Answer (score 6):

Use this formula for `AM`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR($A$1:$A$100)<12))
```

For `PM` replace `<` by `>=`

If your range might contain blank cells and you want to avoid counting them, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(A1:A100)*(HOUR($A$1:$A$100)<12))
```

Comment: Why SUMPRODUCT? and not SUM? where is the 2nd arg?

Comment: @user1016274 `SUMPRODUCT` with one argument behaves just like `SUM` but in array formulas it doesn't need to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Answer (score 4):

Try these two User Defined Functions:

```
Public Function KountPM(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Text
        If Len(s) > 1 Then
            If Right(s, 2) = "PM" Then KountPM = KountPM + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Function

Public Function KountAM(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Text
        If Len(s) > 1 Then
            If Right(s, 2) = "AM" Then KountAM = KountAM + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: Your "COUNTIF" formulas will only work if the cell contains only the time, not the time and date as the original question requires.

Comment: @RobG  you are correct.  I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) with the **SUM** and **HOUR** functions to perform the calculation. E.g., assuming the timestamps are stored in cells A1 through A100, you could use the formulas below:

```
AM     =SUM((HOUR(A1:A100)<12)*1)
PM     =SUM((HOUR(A1:A100)>11)*1)
```

After entering the formulas, hit control-shift-enter, i.e., hit those three keys simultaneously. The formulas will then be displayed as shown below:

```
AM     {=SUM((HOUR(A1:A100)<12)*1)}
PM     {=SUM((HOUR(A1:A100)>11)*1)}
```

[Example of counting AM and PM values in an Excel worksheet](http://support.moonpoint.com/software/office/excel/count-by-hour/)